# Getting Thévenin equivalent when there's a current source only

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, thevenin

I am stuck finding the Thévenin voltage in this circuit.

[image]

What I did first is remove the current source and replace it with an open circuit. After that I got the Thévenin resistance which is the equivalent resistance of the circuit. R-equivalent = 10 + 20 + 10 = 40. So now how do I get the Thévenin voltage (Thévenin equivalent)?

Comment: You might want to check your first calculation.

Comment: It's simply 10 volts in series with 10 ohms by visual inspection and the mildest mental arithmetic. Can you see why?

Comment: @Andyaka how did you get the 10 ohms ? sorry but i'm really bad at circuits...like really really bad lol. I thought i am supposed to get the equivalent resistance of the 3 resistors! and why is the thevenin equivalent 10 volts

Comment: @SpehroPefhany did i get the resistance wrong ?

Comment: Resistance between a and b has 20\$\Omega\$ in parallel with 10\$\Omega\$ + 10\$\Omega\$ in series.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany but we removed the current source which is replaced with an open circuit...does the 20 ohm resistor remains in parallel with the two 10 ohms resistor ?

Comment: @AhmadBenos resistance of a circuit is NOT unique. It depends on which two points you look from. As an example, resistance on the right end, between \$a\$ and \$b\$ is different from the resistance on the left end.  Looking from the right end, the resistance is \$20 || (10+10)\$. Looking from the left end, the resistance is \$10||(10+20)\$. These are not same.

Comment: Draw it out. Yes.

Comment: @beccaboo My instructor said that we should to the opposite of the current source which is when 20 is parallel to the two ohms resistors. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the circuit can be redrawn as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwc7T0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Calculate the total resistance across the current source.  Use Ohms Law to determine the voltage across R1.  That same voltage is across the series combination of R2 & R3.  Now calculate the voltage across R3.

Comment: That's wrong what you have said. You have to measure the resistance from the side of ab. And the thevenin voltage across R3. Not R1. I will include reference from book of Alexander,  Sadiku

Answer (score -1):

There are two processes to find it. The first one is using source transformation. The 2A current source and the 10 ohms resistance in parallel can be replaced by a voltage source of 20 volts and a series resistance of 10 ohms.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqGQHN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, from this circuit, you will get Thevenin resistace= 10 ohms and Thevenin voltage = 10 volts.

Another method is applying the rule;

Thevenin voltage = Thevenin resistance x Short circuit current of the load terminal

According to this,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc8f62.png)</sup>

The short circuit current is calculated using the current divider law. This will also give Thevenin voltage = 10 volts.

Comment: Note the direction of the current source. When doing the source transformation, it should really be -20V or change the polarity of your voltage source.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Didn't noticed that

Comment: Please don't give out answers to homework problems so easily. We expect the OP to do some work and tell us specifically where they are stuck.

Comment: Look closer. I've applied the current divider law. 1 amp flowing through the short-circuited line then through 10 ohms. Another 1 ampere is flowing through the 10 ohms resistance at the left side. No current will flow through the 20 ohms resistor under short circuit condition.

Comment: I've checked again. Please, provide your answer. It would be helpful for finding a mistake if it is made.